# Solving a system by using Cholesky Decomposition $\mathbf L\mathbf D\mathbf L^\top$

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    4 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 2 & -1 \\
    1 & -1 & 3
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1  \\
    x_2  \\
    x_3 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    3  \\
    1  \\
    \frac{3}{2} 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Show that the matrix above is positive definite and solve the system using the decomposition $A = \mathbf L\mathbf D\mathbf L^\top$ with $\mathbf L$ unit triangular and $\mathbf D$ diagonal.

I think I can use the decomposition below:

[image: decomposition]

So we have

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    4 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 2 & -1 \\
    1 & -1 & 3
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    D_1  \\
    L_{21}D_1 & L_{21}^2D_1+D_2  \\
    L_{31}D_1 & L_{31}L_{21}D_1+L_{32}D_2 & L_{31}^2D_1+L_{32}^2D_2 + D_3
\end{bmatrix}$$

But what do I do with the other coefficients of the matrix which are not equal to the right side? I mean, what do I do with $a_{12}, a_{13}$ for example?

And how do I proceed to solve the system?

Answer (score 1):

If you have $LDL^Tx=b$, multiply on the left by $L^{-1}$ to get 
$$
DL^Tx=L^{-1}b. 
$$
So you have a system $Dy=L^{-1}b$, with $D$ diagonal; then you simply have $y_j=(L^{-1}b)_j/D_{jj}$ for each $j$. Since $y=L^Tx$, you have $x=(L^{T})^{-1}y$, which you can calculate directly.

Comment: Why multplying on the left by $L^T$ cancels $L$?

Comment: Because $L$ is unitary. That's what you wrote?